# Vtiger 6.2 Ticket Generating issue

Tags: crm, vtiger

Help me

Recently i updated My Vtiger 6.0 to 6.2 i m getting a issue in saving tickets when we are creating a ticket from dashboard its generating a ticket id assign to and date but it not showing in Tickets. ticket count is same as old. its creating a ticket giving ticket a ID but its not saving any data in it Neither title nor any other information rather then created by and date& time

You can find screenshort there

http://postimg.org/gallery/2j33z9jpw/2c090b33/

there is 5 images

1 image of screenshot of tickets totally 12 tickets
2 images creating a new ticket
3 image after save its showing this to currently tickets its doesnot save anything information contact or else
4 image is screenshot of again tickets section its still 12 in count
5 image u can find in recently edited ticket there is a ticket with unknown title u can find it with take your mouse on it. this is the ticket we created. its showing blank reason it doesn't save any information no have titles tht reason its show blank

Kindly help me find how we can solve this

Regards
Rajnesh

Comment: I suggest you to install a clean 6.2 version (only for tests) and check if the problem still happens.

Comment: oh ok. you wanna i check it if its working or not?  if working then compare both right/?/

Comment: Yes, basically I want to exclude that the problem is related to the upgrade of an old version. 
If you want to make test on a similar environment, you could copy your vTiger db in a local machine (make a backup before) and wire a fresh vTiger installation to it.

Comment: yup its can may be work.. thanks will try...